# Why does this combination of strtol and strtok not work?

Tags: c++, strtok, strtol

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    long int a = strtol(strtok("1-2-3-4","-"),(char**)NULL,10);
    cout << a <<endl
}
```

I'm running on Solaris Unix. It's giving me a segmentation fault.

The fault is in `strtol()`.

Answer (score 1):

The problems are legion.

I would expect that the core dump is because the string `"1-2-3-4"` is stored in read-only memory, so when `strtok()` modifies it (to isolate the first token), the program crashes.  You say the crash is in `strtol()`; that would suggest that the return value from `strtok()` is NULL.

The first call to `strtok()` uses the string as an argument; the second call passes NULL in its place to indicate 'continue where you left off last time'.  As written, if the string was modifiable, then you'd parse `1` four times.

This is closer to correct (though untested):

```
char  input[] = "1-2-3-4";
char *data = input;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    char *token = strtok(data, "-");
    if (token != 0)
    {
        long int a = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    data = NULL;
}
```

In general, you need to do error detection from `strtol()`; further, doing so is quite fraught.  However, with the sample string, you would not have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the `strtok` call, not with `strtol`.  You can't call `strtok` on a string literal, since it's going to try to modify the string.  Modifying a string literal causes undefined behaviour in C++.

Answer (score 1):

As the problem is already discussed, I'd like to show an alternate approach :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main ()
    {
      long int a;
      char str[] ="1-2-3-4";
      char * pch;

      pch = strtok (str,"-");
      while (pch != NULL)
      {
         a = strtol(pch,(char**)NULL,10);
         cout << a <<endl;

        pch = strtok (NULL, "-");
      }
      return 0;
     }
```